# Print the data from second column

Tags: awk

I am having a file called fixed.txt as shown below:

```
Column1                   | Column2 | Column3
Total expected ratio      | 53      | 68
Total number|count number | 54      | 72
reset|print|total         | 64      | 84
```

I am trying to print the output  column2 as below:

```
Fixed.txt:
53
54
64
```

I tried the below script but I am not getting the desired output.

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in fixed.txt
do
awk -F" | "
    NR>1
    awk '{ print $2 }' fixed.txt
done
```

Can we use pipeline(**|**) and space at a time as a delimiter?

Comment: You're mixing awk and shell syntax really badly. You have `awk -F" | "` not followed by an awk script, then you have `NR>1` in bash when I assume it's supposed to be part of an awk script, THEN you have an awk script. You then have the whole thing wrapped in a shell loop which will only loop 1 time and setting a variable that you never use. awk and shell are 2 completely different tools each with their own syntax, semantics, etc. You should try to find a tutorial on shell fundamentals and a separate tutorial on awk fundamentals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following based on your shown samples it's written. Written and tested in
https://ideone.com/WoF40j

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
}
{
  print $(NF-1)+0
}
' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Use space and `|` as a field delimiter one could run following.

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]+\\|[[:blank:]]+' '{print $(NF-1)}'  Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk -F' +\\| +' '{print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

Comment: it is working but can we use pipeline and space at a time as a delimiter?

Comment: @ADAPANIKHIL, yes please it's tested in mentioned link, it's working kindly check it once. I have written it in mobile, will add one more solution in few mins too.